# How to avoid MemoryError with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a Flask server that has to perform some operations on a lot of images. It receives that images from client.

In order to perform as soon as possible, I'm using `multiprocessing` module and I have assigned every image to a process.

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(files_path, '*')):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_single_model,args=[filename, models_path, num_model_photos, uid, i])
    process.start()
```

In `create_single_model`:

```
def create_single_model(filename, models_path, num_model_photos, uid,i):
    original_name = os.path.basename(filename).split(".", 1)  # takes file's name removing the extension type

    img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    mask, orientations = morpho_otsu(filename)  # computes mask and orientation from the image file
    name_with_orientation = orientations + "_" + original_name[0]

    save_masked_image(models_path, name_with_orientation, img, mask)  # save mode
    percentage = round((i / num_model_photos) * 100)
```

The problem is that with more than 25 images, so more than 25 processes, the RAM become full. It gives me `MemoryError` and it crashes.

I think that the problem is that I create all processes and I allocate the memory for all processes and then I start it.

Is there a solution to define a fixed number of processes in order to stop creating other processes(and allocate memory for it) and restart when another process is terminated? Maybe using `Pool` instead of `Process`?

Comment: Use a [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

Comment: Yes, use a `Pool`